# Picking even numbers using recursion

Tags: python, list, recursion

Here I have defined a function that takes in a list and returns the count of the even numbers in that same list.When I run the program I get None in return.

```
def count_even(lst, c = 0):
    """
    parameters : a lst of type list
    returns : the even elements from that list
    """
    if lst == []:
        return c
    if lst[0] % 2 == 0:
        c += 1
    else:
        return count_even(lst[1:])


print(count_even([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]))
```

Where is my problem?

Comment: Here `c` will each time be `0`, you simply assign to the local `c` a different value, but you can not change the state of the `int` `c` is referring to. In your second case, you even do not return `c` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two basic problems with the current implementation:

1. `c` is an `int`, and `int`s are immutable. If you change `c`, this thus does *not* mean the `c` in recursive calls is "updated", each recursive call `c` will have as value `0`; and
2. you do not return a value in case the first item is even, so Python will return `None` in that case.

```
def count_even(lst, c = 0):
    if lst == []:
        return c
    if lst[0] % 2 == 0:
        c += 1
    # no else
    return count_even(lst[1:], c+1)  # pass a new value for c
```

A more compact representation is however:

```
def count_even(lst, c = 0):
    if not lst:
        return c
    return count_even(lst[1:], c + 1 - lst[0] % 2)
```

Note however that *linear* recursion is typically not a good idea, since the call stack will grow with the number of elements, and thus easily result in an overflow (especially since Python does not implement *tail call optimization (TCO)*).

Answer (score 7):

In case `lst[0] % 2 == 0`, you are not returning anything (thus implicitly returning `None`). You also never include the updated value of `c` in the recursion. Change that to

```
if lst == []:
    return c

if lst[0] % 2 == 0:
    c += 1

return count_even(lst[1:], c)
```

and you're good. Since the other answers include some nifty alternative solutions, I'll go ahead and nominate

```
def count_even(lst):
    return 1 - lst[0]%2 + count_even(lst[1:]) if lst else 0
```

as well.

Answer (score 1):

You almost did it. Just a simple correction. You are calling the recursion in else block which is not right. You should consider it outside the block. Check the below code :

```
def count_even(lst, c = 0):
    """
    parameters : a lst of type list
    returns : the even elements from that list
    """
    if lst == []:
        return c
    if lst[0] % 2 == 0:
        c = c + 1
    return c + count_even(lst[1:])


print(count_even([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]))
```